# Does Amazon Mobile have a URI scheme to allow other apps to open Amazon Mobile on the iPhone?

Tags: mobile-application, url-scheme

How do you have an app redirect to Mobile Amazon's app from within another app? Can this be done from within AWS's API? Or is there a URI scheme (eg. amazon://amazon)

Comment: Did you find a scheme for opening an Amazon product page in the Amazon app on iOS?